# A single `remote: true` form tag will not generate requests as type: `js` in my rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-rails

Basically I can't get a form with `remote: true` to submit as an xhr request.

It's been a long time since I've worked with a `html.erb` and `js.erb` based front end so I'm probably doing something dumb here

Using Ruby 2.5.7 and rails 4.2.11 and I'm using `gem 'jquery-rails'`.

My `application.js` contains:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui.js
//= require safari_form_submission_workaround.js
```

We have many forms in our app that use `form_tag` with `remote: true` to make an ajax request but a specific one will not work. It sends the request with the header `Content-Type text/html` and then throws an error because it can't find a corresponding template because it is not looking for something with a `js.erb` suffix

The html that generates the form is:

```
 <%= form_tag waitlist_item_creator_path, id: 'item_creator', remote: true do %>
```

and the rendered html is

```
<form id="item_creator" action="/waitlist_item_creator" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
```

I have verified that the jQuery `$` is available in this context.
The specific error is: `ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template order_items/create_waitlist_line_item, application/create_waitlist_line_item with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:` which seems to indicate it is looking for the wrong format based on the request header.

Any thoughts on what could be going wrong here or how I could be smarter about debugging it? Any other way to force this to submit as a js request? I have spent a stupid amount of time on this.

Comment: It sounds like `rails_ujs` isn't hooking into the form somehow. does the rendered element have `data-remote="true"` on it? The syntax might require `data: { remote: true }`

Comment: @JoshBrody  yes edited above to show the rendered html. It does contain it. I'll try the formal hash syntax

Comment: is the html you provided the actual html? because that has a quote issue if that is indeed the html.

Comment: @JoshBrody no that quote issue was a copying error. I corrected above.  Switching to the other set up unfortunately did not do it although I appreciate the help.

Comment: If the request is being sent as a normal synchronous request (which you can verify from the network tab in web inpector) then something is definitely messing with the handler. Check the browser console.